# Obtaining the selected choice from a PHP selection list as a variable

Tags: php

I am a new PHP user so please forgive me if this question is trivial.  I would like to store the user's selection when they make a choice from a selection list.  For example, if a selection list has "Green", "Blue" and "Red" in its dropdown list and the user selects "Red", is there a PHP variable that holds the value 'Red" that I can use?  I looked at the attributes for Select and Option and made a few attempts, but no success.  Thank you very much.  Below is my code to create the simple dropdown list.  I realize I can use a Form action option but would like to collect this variable while on this form, if possible.

```
<head><title>Dropdown Selection</title></head>
<body>
<form action='CimquestQuotingEngine.php' method='POST'>
<select name='ColorBoxName'>
<?php
function fSetColorDropdown($MyQuery)
{
$user="JP";
$host="";
$password="";
$database="";
$loginName="JP";

$cxn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database) or die ("Cannot connect to server"); 
$result=mysqli_query($cxn,$MyQuery) or Die ("Couldn't execute Query");


while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
extract($row);
echo "<option value='ColorName'>$ColorName</option>\n";
}
Return;
}
$MyQuery="SELECT ColorName FROM F400ABSM30ColorTable";

fSetColorDropdown($MyQuery);

?>
</select>
<input type='submit' value='Click to Select' />
```

Comment: Do you want to get the value once the form has been posted (then look into `$_POST`) or while the user is still filling in the form (-> JavaScript)?

Comment: PHP won't have access to the user selection until after the form is submitted.  Then, the selection will be contained in `$_POST['ColorBoxName']`.

Comment: Some background, PHP executes on the server and renders HTML code that is sent to the client (browser). This all happens before the user gets to interact with the form. While the user interacts with the form you have Javascript to work with. To get information back to the server you have the option of GET, POST, or Javascript XHR. Question, where do you want to store the user selection? In a database on the server? Or in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

You can send this variable to your php with http request (for example with ajax or form post). Php is preprocessed so everything is compiled and run before printing html to user window therefore what you're trying to do is unachieveable.